# ComponentDidMount I want to add fetch API and FirebaseAuth

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, fetch-api

I want to connect firebase stuff. What I'm trying in my news feed is when I press `addTofavourite` its name should go to firebase. So in my code for fetch, I used `componentDidMount` and for sending too there is `componentDidMount`. I have no idea how to connect them.

This is what I tried, but it's not working.

```
componentDidMount() {
   firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword
   ("web@imandy.ie", "123456")
//////////////////////////////////////
   this.fetchNews();
  }
```

for fetching news

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchNews();
  }
```

for firebase thing

```
componentDidMount() {

        firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("web@imandy.ie", "123456" )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this

```js
componentDidMount = async () => {
   const { user }  = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword("web@imandy.ie", "123456");
   // If you want to use user detail, write code here
   // ...
   this.fetchNews();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to call this function in componentWillReciveProps(){} or componentDidUpdate(){}